# How do I open a Netbeans empty file in Java/

Tags: java, netbeans

Here's my Netbeans project structure:

[image]

`Maine` is the class with `main`. I want to read the lines of text in the Netbeans "empty file" `HighlightInput` with a `Scanner` object, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Because of what works for a different project (see below), I tried this (and a lot of other things):

```
    InputStream myStream = null;

    myStream =  Class.forName("gbl/Maine").getClassLoader() //// exception here
                     .getResourceAsStream("HighlightInput");
  Path p = Paths.get(myStream.toString());
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(p);
```

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gbl/Maine`

Because of something else that also works below, I tried this:

```
  File file = new File("src/HighlightInput");      
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);          //// exception here

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\HighlightInput (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

**What should I do to read the file "HighlightInput"?**

=========================

Here's why I tried what I did--I followed two different apparent patterns, unsuccessfully:

Here's what works for a different project (`Masterwords` contains `main`), structure listed below, to read Netbeans file named "Help":

```
  myStream =  Class.forName("masterwords.Masterwords").getClassLoader()
      .getResourceAsStream("Help");
```

[image]

The following works to read the file named "dictionary":

```
File file = new File("src/dictionary");
Path in_path = file.toPath();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    InputStream myStream = Maine.class.getResourceAsStream("/HighlightInput");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myStream, "UTF-8");
```

Resources are no File, but may reside in a `.jar`. In the same jar/same classes dir, you may use something like `getClass().getResource(...)`. This is relative to the classes package directory, hence the "/Highlight" which corresponds to the root dir aka default package.

The scanner may immediate work on that InputStream. It is needed to indicate the character set encoding, as otherwise the local operating system encoding is taken - unportable.

If you want to *write* to the resource file: don't - because of the normal case of compiling to a .jar as distributed application. Use the resource in that case as a template and copy it to some directory in the user's home directory.

Comment: THANKS, @Joop. What you wrote worked fine. This is one of the hardest tasks I've come across. Netbeans Help didn't. But could you please tell me how to fix this line: `myStream =  Class.forName("gbl/Maine"). getClassLoader(). getResourceAsStream("/HighlightInput");`. I don't know what the heck the Netbeans directory structure is, nor what class name to use. And I'd like to know why; otherwise, this will be a permanent problem. If you have the time.

Comment: Try `Class.forName("gbl.Maine").getClassLoader(). getResourceAsStream("HighlightInput");`. With getClassLoader no heading `/`.

Comment: I swear I tried that--I tried a dozen permuations--but THANK YOU, it did work. Slash vs. dot; slash vs. no character. I think the need to NOT have the slash in the stream name prefix was what stopped me from getting it. THANK YOU, @Joop!